# ASP.Net MVC4 & Bootstrap: Tab Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I got the following view that is shown in a Bootstrap Dialog. When I click submit the fields in tab 1 are validated. I filled them out and then click submit again, but the fields in tab 2 and 3 are not validated, even they are marked as required. It seems like the visible fields are the ones that are been validating.

How do I validate the form using bootstrap tabs?

```
@model Modelos.JuegoDTO

@{
    Layout = null;
}


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("agregar", "generos", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" },
        new
        {
            id = "AgregarForm",
            enctype = "multipart/form-data"
        }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-735134">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#panel-444828" data-toggle="tab">General</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-391505" data-toggle="tab">Imagenes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#panel-391506" data-toggle="tab">Video</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-444828">

@*                <fieldset>
                    <legend>General</legend>*@

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeneroId)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GeneroId,
            new SelectList(Model.ListaGeneros, "Id", "Nombre"), "Seleccione un genero")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GeneroId)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsolaId)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ConsolaId,
            new SelectList(Model.ListaConsolas, "Id", "Nombre"), "Seleccione una consola")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConsolaId)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activo)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activo)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activo)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @*</fieldset>*@

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-391505">
@*                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Imagenes</legend>*@

                    <div class="row-fluid">

                        <a href="#" id="add">Agregar Imagen</a>

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListaImagenes)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListaImagenes)

                        <div id="divImagenesDTO">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @*</fieldset>*@
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-391506">
@*                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Video</legend>*@
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoYouTube)
                        </div>
                        <div class="span8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoYouTube)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoYouTube)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @*</fieldset>*@
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
                <button id="btnSalvar" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}



@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/juegos-imagenes.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/juegos-modal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the fields in each "begin from" will be validated, as they are ultimately rendered as their own form tags.

If you want them all validated at the same time, you will have to have the entire tab content in one beginform, with a viewmodel to cover all the inputs from all the tabs.